# What does __dyld_dyld_fatal_error_disassembly mean?

Tags: ios4

I have an Iphone app that was nearing its development completion and literally between "build and run"s this error appeared. I commented out all of the code that might be offending the simulator but nothing could make the error resolve. I put a couple of NSLogs in the app delegate to see how far the application was getting before it crashes and nothing appeared from the console.  It appears the app is loading its splash screen and then dying. I'm an intermediate Iphone developer but I can not decipher that error message. Did my simulator get corrupted or something similar? I didn't add any new libraries or any thing drastic to the code in between builds. I also tried cleaning the build file, and deleting the app on the simulator and force a re-install.

Any help would be great. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me and this is how I got it working (XCode 4):
In the Product menu, select Manage Schemes. Select the scheme you're using and click edit. Click the Run build type in the column on the left and the Diagnostics tab at the top.
I unchecked all of the checkboxes and the error you're describing went away. I didn't spend the time to discover which specific checkbox or combination was the culprit. 
I was only getting the error when I tried to run on a device.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a clean before you build again? There might be some leftover files doing some nasty things to your build.

Past that, have you tried using [breakpoints and the debugger to step through your program](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html) and see exactly what threads/operations are causing the problem?

Finally, are you testing on the device, too? The simulator is not an accurate representation of running the application on the actual hardware.

Comment: I tried using breakpoints and going through the code that way but the app wasn't even loading.  I finally gave up and re-built the project from scratch. It didn't take as long as i thought it would.  I'm thinking the project was corrupted when i migrated to different versions of XCode. Lesson learned...stick with one version of Xcode through the development cycle.  Thanks so much for your suggestions.

Comment: Were you using source control to manage your work while you were using different versions?

Comment: Yes i was, to be honest my team had a very difficult time getting the repository to work. I think in general the lesson was to have everyone on the same version of Xcode at all times. This would prevent many problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Guard Malloc** has to be disabled in the Product Menu, Edit Scheme..., Run section, Memory Management.